# jQuery .on() не работает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

И так, проблема:
Есть мобильный сайт. На нем jq. Есть две кнопки, находятся на разных позициях в DOM. схема примерно такая:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <ul class="table-view">
    <li class="promt">
      <a class="icon icon-right-nav" style="font-size: 14px;">Подсказка</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content-padded">
    <a id="answer">Решение</a>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
      });
      $(document).on("click", "#answer", function(){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Так вот, в браузере с десктопа работает, а с телефона нет. НО! Обработчик для кнопки `#answer` работает как часы! Не работает только `.promt`. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашел на англоязычном Stackoverflow. Магия заключалась в том, что safari не хочет принимать такие события, или хочет, но только при подключении к body. Решением является подключение `onclick=""` к элементу, на который вешают обработчик. "Странно, но работает", как сказал тот форумчанин. В итоге конечный код выглядит так:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="table-view">
        <li onclick="" class="promt">
            <a class="icon icon-right-nav" style="font-size: 14px;">Подсказка</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content-padded">
        <a onclick="" id="answer">Решение</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#answer", function(){
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'li a', function(){
        alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#answer", function(){
        alert($(this).attr("class"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Нет, все данные подгружаются AJAX-ом поэтому мне нужны именно делегированные события.

Comment: Ок, но суть ответа в селекторе "li a".

Comment: все равно не работает. Ответ нашел на англоязычном Stackoverflow. Магия заключалась в том, что safari не хочет принимать такие события, или хочет, но только при подключении к body. Решением является подключение `onclick=""` к элементу, на который вешают обработчик. "Странно, но работает", как сказал тот форумчанин. Щас еще это же оформлю в виде ответа.

Comment: Вы вариант мой пробовали? Если для #answer заработало, то должно заработать и для другого  тега a

Comment: конечно попробовал. Вот не работает и всё(

Comment: даже `li *` не работает